# Find and replace plain text with merge field in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2016

I have an email template that currently has tokens like `[[cost]]`. However, I am now transitioning to using formal merge fields, which look like `«cost»`.

I have the old format at *lot* in this template, so it is very inconvenient to manually copy-paste the new format. I tried using simple find and replace, but Word does not recognize the replacement text as a field.

How can I use find and replace or some similarly easy method to replace all occurrences of `[[cost]]` with a merge field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this one out pretty quickly!

Select the field and copy. Then, in the normal find and replace window, put `^c` in the Replace with field.